# RDD API Python how to make a count

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a file with elements like this :

1,1_id,lucas,10

2,2_is,pierre,30

2,3_id,lucas,20

I would like such result :

[(lucas,30),(pierre,30)]

I need to use only RDD way.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your desired output seems like the sum instead of the count. Please update the question with what you have tried. S/O users will assist you in the right direction instead of provide you with a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy.

```py
# get last two elements
def f(s):
    s_list = s.split(',')
    return (s_list[2], int(s_list[3]))

r = sc.textFile('YOUR_FILE').\
        map(lambda line:f(line)).\
        reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```